# Making a New Directory on input Issue.

Tags: php

When I go To Submit to make a New Directory, It Isn't making the director name that I Input "$newclient". Example I'm trying to make a folder called Trail, and then I input it and submit it, It will make a directory name $newclient not the name Trail. Any Ideas Why It's doing that and how to possibly fix it? Thank You In Advance! :)

Heres the PHP that I'm using to try to make a Directory after submit:

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submitnewclient']))
    {
        $newclient = $_POST['newclient'];
        if (!file_exists('../photos/$newclient')) {
    mkdir('../photos/$newclient', 0777, true);
}
    }


?>
<h1>
<?php echo $newclient ?>
</h1>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
            <h1> Make New Folder For A Client</h1>
<form action="newclient.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select User to Upload to: 
    <input type="text" name="newclient" id="newclient" cols="10" rows="1"> </input>
    <input type="submit" value="New Client" id="submitnewclient" name="submitnewclient">
</form>
```

Comment: instead of `'../photos/$newclient'`, use `"../photos/$newclient"`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat   Haha Whoop! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to use *PHP* variables within the strings. So your code would become:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submitnewclient']))
    {
        $newclient = $_POST['newclient'];
        if (!file_exists("../photos/$newclient")) {
    mkdir("../photos/$newclient", 0777, true);
}
    }


?>
```

Comment: It is all about practice. You will eventually master it. Good Luck!